# Cancel removing a directory, and want to find out what have been removed

Tags: files, rm, timestamps

I was removing a directory by `rm -r mydir` and cancelled it in the middle. How can I find out what have been removed under the directory?

Does remove a content of a directory change the timestamp of the directory? Modification, access, or change timestamps?

I have a backup from two weeks ago. about 30% changes happened since then: new subdirectories, and files move between subdirectories, etc. How can I compare between my current dir and its old backup?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have GNU diff, you can run it on both directories - it should report differing and missing (or new) files.

Comment: @muru: Thanks. Is it sufficient to check only those files or directories appearing in the backup not in the current source, and ignore those only appearing in the current source not in the backup, and ignore those files appearing in both but differ?

Comment: I think so, since the third is essentially a superset of the second.

Comment: The 3rd isn't a superset of the 2nd? I asked if it is sufficient ignoring BOTH 3rd AND 2nd, and only focus on the 1st?

Comment: It is, and again, yes.

Comment: `diff -rqy dir1 dir2` reports the three kinds, where 3rd seems not a superset of 2nd?

Comment: I'm talking of the sense of the three types. Can you nitpick any more?

Comment: I am not nipicking you. :) I understand we may talk about different things. I just want to make sure if I can ignore the last two kinds reported by diff, just for the sake of recovering my deleted files and dirs as much as possible, while keep the change made after the last backup.

Comment: Take an example: `x` is in backup (`b`), not in current (`c`) - `x` was deleted or moved. `x` is not in `b`, but in  `c` - `x` is a new file created by you, untouched by your accidental `rm`. `x` is in `b`, but different in `c` - `x` is file modified by you, untouched by `rm` - `unlink` doesn't leave things half-done. So you will only restore the first kind, since the backup doesn't have anything constructive to do with the latter two.